# Which is the better way , die or echo for ajax response?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am using AJAX in one of my web pages like this.
I have specified dataType as JSON here.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url:  "www.mydomain.com/ajax.php",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data:{to_email_address:"myemail@gmail.com"},
    success:function(response){
        response = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
        if(response){
            alert("success");
        }
        else{
            alert("Failed, Try again");
        }
    }
});
```

In the `ajax.php`, i use `echo` `json_encode` function as follows

```
<?php
    if(!($mail_to_address, $mail_subject, $content, $headers)) {
        echo json_encode(false);
    }
    else{
        echo json_encode(true);
    }
?>
```

But I have seen somewhere , using `die` instead of `echo` just like

```
<?php
    if(!($mail_to_address, $mail_subject, $content, $headers)) {
        die(json_encode(false));
    }
    else{
        die(json_encode(true));
    }
?>
```

Can anybody please explain which is the better way and why?
Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you `echo` and don't `die`, you run the risk of mistakenly producing more output someday than required, later down the lines.

If you `die`, it prints and ends everything right there. That's the only difference.

Here is an example using your code

```
<?php
    if(!($mail_to_address, $mail_subject, $content, $headers)) {
        echo json_encode(false);    // a die would stop everything here
    }
    else{
        echo json_encode(true);
    }
    echo "oops this was mistakenly printed";  // this breaks your JSON
?>
```

If you use `die` instead of `echo` then the last `echo` won't break your `JSON` because it will never execute.

If you know there is nothing after your conditional checks, or if you are confident there is no special reason to use `die()`, you can keep using your `echo`. So the answer to your question is: None of them is superior to the other as long as your output is under your control.